# How to get MongoDB Collection list on Streamlit selection box

Tags: python, mongodb, streamlit

I tried to connect the MongoDB server using streamlit selection box feature, but I cant get the collection list on my dropdown selection box. Here's my code

```
%%writefile app.py
import streamlit as st
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np    

st.header('Import Well Log into MongoDB Server')

mongoClient = MongoClient ('mongodb://localhost:27017/')
database_names = mongoClient.list_database_names()
optmongo = st.selectbox('Choose the database',(database_names))

my_db2 = mongoClient.optmongo

collection_list = my_db2.list_collection_names()

optmongo2 = st.selectbox('Choose the collection',(collection_list))
my_cols2 = my_db2.optmongo2
```

Help, this is what I get
[(screenshot streamlit apps)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6zE7.png)

I cant get the list collection names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
my_db2 = mongoClient.optmongo
```

To

```py
my_db2 = mongoClient[optmongo]
```